# Match Error Result and exit program on variable assignment

Tags: rust

I do check function results on assignment using `match` statement. In some cases I want to exit the program with an error message like `panic!()` does. But how can I create a function or macro that can be used everywhere?

Example:

```rust
let args = match args::Args::parse() {
    Ok(args) => args,
    Err(e) => someerror("bla")
};
let mut statedoc = match state_loader.load() {
    Ok(states) => states,
    Err(e) => someerror("blub")
};
```

What does `someerror()` need to return to work everywhere?

Comment: `someerror` doesn't need to return anything, but its implementation can panic or print an error and exit the process. In other words, you can call `panic!(s)` inside `someerror` or, if you don't want your program to panic, you can call `eprintln!("{}", s); std::process::exit(1);`.

Comment: No, Rust will not compile this because the return type of someerror() doesn't match.

Comment: That depends on the return type - see dianhenglau's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use [diverging function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#the-never-type-that-never-returns). Use the following syntax:

```rust
fn someerror(msg: &str) -> ! { // Note the `-> !` here
    eprintln!("Error: {}", msg);
    panic!();
}

fn main() {
    let r: Result<i32, &str> = Err("hello");
    let x = match r {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(e) => someerror(e),
    };
    println!("x = {}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `main` can return a `Result` and you can use the `?`-operator everywhere:

```
fn foo() -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
    Err("Nope!")
}

fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let x = 5 * foo()?;
    println!("{}", x);
    Ok(())
}
```

When executed, the above program will just print "Error: Nope!" and have an exit status not equal to zero. To support more kinds of errors, you can have a a custom `enum` to wrap those and appropriate implementations of `Into`, so you can just do `let args = args::Args::parse()?;`. Any errors will bubble up to `main()` and cause the error to be printed out.

Comment: But than I have to implement every type. I don't think panic!() does it this way as it cannot know every type.